# デベロッパーツールに「GET .../main.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND」

Tags: javascript

アドバイスを下さった皆様ありがとうございます！
アドバイスを参考にさせていただきながらmain.jsを読み込めない原因を探していたのですが、
こちらのファイルの横にMやUと表示されているこちらは特に関係ないのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードにミスが見当たらないのですがこちらのメッセージはどうしたら解決できますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 表示されたメッセージも質問文として書き出してください。また画像もせめてトリミングしてください。

Comment: Consoleメッセージに書いてある通り、`file:///Users/MAKOTO/Desktop/MyJS/js/main.js`のファイルが見つからないということでしょう。ブラウザからの見え方なので`file://`が付いていますが、要はそのマシンのルートフォルダから`/Users`で始まるそのパスの場所に該当のファイルが無い(ように見える：アクセス権が無いとか？)わけです。確認してください。

Comment: 後ろに見える`M`よりも、`main.js`の前にいかにもフォルダを示しているように見える`js`は、単なるファイル種別をあらわすアイコンなので、それをパスの一部に付けてはいけません。例えばindex.htmlソース内に`./js/main.js`とか書いてあるとそれは間違いで、`js/`を外した`./main.js`になるはずです。

Comment: コードの質問であるなら (自分ではミスが無いと思っていても) 質問に **コードの中身** を含めておいた方が役立つ回答を付けやすいと思います。 / `M` などのマークは VSCode で編集されたファイルに対して表示されるものでしょう。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index.html`の17行目に、`main.js`を参照している`<script>`があるはずです。

- `main.js` を読む必要がないなら、`<script>`を削除します。
- `main.js` が必要で、`<script>` が正しいなら、`Desktop/MyJS/js/main.js` を用意します。
- `main.js` が必要で、`main.js` はすでに用意してあり、`main.js` を移動したくないなら、`<script>` に指定しているURLを修正します。`main.js` と `index.html` が同じディレクトリにある場合、`<script src="main.js"></script>` などになります。

Comment: ファイルのコードの指定が間違えていました！ありがとうございました！